# Google wallet abandons inapp purchases on march 2 2015

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, in-app-billing, android-pay

I was thinking to implement Google play in-app purchases into my app. But i have heard Google wallet abandons inapp purchases on March 2 2015.

So anybody knows what exactly will be abandoned. Can i implement in-app purchases in my app and if i do so how will handle all the orders which will come in Google wallet(Google checkout).

As of now i have put in-app billing inside my app and released. But now  i saw in this link [here](http://www.pymnts.com/news/2014/google-wallet-abandons-in-app-purchases/#.VNxucPmUd1Y) that Google wallet is abandoning inapp purchases, so not sure what exactly they are abandoning. Please someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android / Google Play in-app purchases are not affected.

The deprecations announcement applies only to the web-based in-app payments API.

More details here:

https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/6107573

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confusion surrounding this, it doesn't affect in app purchases at all so don't worry.

Check out https://plus.google.com/+RonAmadeo/posts/DqN6UX6zryx

and

https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/6107573